# Which ML algorithm to use if we have categorical data, numeric data, derived data (derived from) other variable in our data set?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, model-selection, machine-learning-model

I am a beginner in Data Science. I have a data set which contains numerical data, categorical data and derived data (derived from other columns). The target column (dependent) is binary. Which Machine Learning algorithm will predict my target column most accurate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chose a Machine Learning algorithm?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38305/how-to-chose-a-machine-learning-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

This question is way too vague, you just describes pretty much a standard situation. Which algorithm / method you use depends entirely on your objective and data. You should provide more information if you want a specific answer. Since your dependent variable is binary you are interested in classification, popular algorithms are Random Forests, Logistic Regression, K-means, etc.

Comment: i meant to ask that, i have around 50 columns in my data set (numeric, categorical), how to decide which column i should use while building my model ?

Comment: If you believe you have a lot of noise in your data, a lot of unnecessary variables, you can filter them out first with a feature selection algorithm. Some classifiers do this automatically, such as LASSO or Random Forests.

Comment: Thanks..
one more question. there is a column with more than 50% NA values (categorical). so can we remove it ?

Comment: Short answer is no, unless the variable is uninteresting to the objective. The topic of missing data is complex and deep, you should research it a little.